# Create a data frame from another containing a hierarchical taxonomy based on a column

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a table containing a hierarchical structure of some categories:

for example

"cat" belongs to "domestic animals", and "domestic animals" belong to "animals"

below I show my data with segment.parent that tells the macro-category to which each entity belongs to. I want to create a new table where I only have the leaves of the hierarchy and a variable for the two macro categories it belongs to

```
segment.id     Name.                 segment.parent
   1            cat                       3
   2            dog                       3
   3            domestic animals          4
   4            animals                   NA
   5            cake                      7
   6            ice-cream                 7
   7            dessert                   8
   8            food                      NA
   9            main-course               8
```

what I want to obtain is the following

```
segment.id     Name                 segment.parent   Name.parent              Name.parent.parent
   1            cat                       3           domestic animals          animals
   2            dog                       3           domestic animals          animals
   5            cake                      7           dessert                   food
   6            ice-cream                 7           dessert                   food
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first thing you must is select the segments that are parents. Those that are not parents will be leaves.

```
parent.ids <- unique(df$segment.parent)
```

Now using the dplyr() library you can filter only those entities whose id's are not parent ids, then join two times to obtain the father categories.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  subset(! segment.id %in% parent.ids) %>%
  left_join(df, by = c("segment.parent" = "segment.id"), suffix = c("", ".x")) %>%
  left_join(df, by = c("segment.parent.x" = "segment.id"), suffix = c("", ".x")) %>%
  select(segment.id, Name., segment.parent, Name.parent = Name..x, Name.parent.parent = Name..x.x) %>%
  print(row.names = F)
```

Output

```
 segment.id       Name. segment.parent      Name.parent Name.parent.parent
          1         cat              3 domestic animals            animals
          2         dog              3 domestic animals            animals
          5        cake              7          dessert               food
          6   ice-cream              7          dessert               food
          9 main-course              8             food               <NA>
```

I've take the liberty of using `left_join()`, which will retrieve rows even when there isn't a father category. That's why *main-course* appears in the output listing. If you want to bring only those items who have at least two level above, you can replace `left_join()` with `inner_join()` instead.

Comment: your solution works, however I don't know why it ends up creating a lots go additional rows every time I use left_join, thus I added a filter using  na.omit(df) after every left_join

Comment: Like I said, it is because left_join bring items that don't have two categories above, maybe there's only one. If you want to avoid it you may used inner_join() instead, so you don't need a filter.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how big of a data set you are working with but my suggestion would be to have a second data set (i.e. `data2`) which holds the corresponding `segment.parent` values along with the other two variables. Then with `dplyr` you can join the data sets and filter the duplicates.

```
library(dplyr)
data3 <- inner_join(data1, data2, by = "segment.parent") %>%
  filter(duplicated(data3))

> data3
  segment.id     Name. segment.parent      Name.parent Name.parent.parent
1          1       cat              3 domestic animals            animals
2          2       dog              3 domestic animals            animals
3          5      cake              7           desert               food
4          6 ice-cream              7           desert               food
```

**Your data:**

```
data1 <- data.frame(segment.id = 1:9,
                    Name. = c("cat", "dog", "domestic animals", "animals", "cake", "ice-cream", "dessert", "food", "main-course"),
                    segment.parent = c(3, 3, 4, NA, 7, 7, 8, NA, 8))

data2  <- data.frame(segment.parent = c(3, 3, 7, 7),
                     Name.parent = c("domestic animals", "domestic animals", "desert", "desert"),
                     Name.parent.parent = c("animals", "animals", "food", "food"))
```

Answer (score 0):

As others have mentioned, I'm not sure how big your dataset is. The below solution is a short-term solution. You may need to reshape your data slightly and look into [pivoting](https://tidyr.tidyverse.org/reference/pivot_wider.html).

```
library(dplyr)

df <- data.frame(segment.id = seq(1, 9),
                 Name = c("cat", "dog",
                           "domestic animals", "animals",
                           "cake", "ice-cream",
                           "dessert", "food",
                           "main-course"),

                 segment.parent = c(3, 3, 4, NA,
                                    7, 7, 8, NA, 8),
                 stringsAsFactors = FALSE)


df %>%
  dplyr::mutate(Name.parent = case_when(
    segment.parent == 3 ~ "domestic animals",
    segment.parent == 7 ~ "dessert",
  )) %>% 
  dplyr::mutate(Name.parent.parent = case_when(
      Name.parent == "domestic animals" ~ "animals",
      Name.parent == "dessert" ~ "food"
  )) %>% 
  na.omit()
```